# dataTable Serverside processing pagination with draw

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using jquery DataTable  1.10.13 . I'm getting showing data as serverside processing. currently my data table shows correct pagination numbers on bottom but all the data shown 4 all paginate pages. [pagination shows 4 pages. but all 4 pages load same data load.]

I saw on tutorial they are passing a variable called 'draw' from model. How can I get that?

below is my code

```
 $('#userTable').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "type": "GET",
            "url": ",
            "dataSrc": "data",
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "dataType": "json",
            "processData": true
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "email" },
            { "data": "company" },

        ]
    } );
```

and this is my controller

```
 public function getUserList1()
    {
    $data = $this->user->getUserListData();
   echo json_encode($data);
}
```

below is my model.

```
  public function getUserListData()
    {

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users  ORDER BY regdate DESC';
        $query = prepare($sql);
        try {
            $query->execute($params);
            $data = $query->fetchAll();
            $total = $query->rowCount();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            \debug::error('MySQL errno ' . $e->getCode() . ': "' . $e->getMessage() . '" when executing: ' . $query->queryString);
        }
        $response = array(
            "draw" => '',
            "recordsTotal" => $total,
            "recordsFiltered" => $total,
            "data" => $users
        );

        return $response;
```

How to get value for   "draw" => ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following option unless you decode request parameters from JSON string:

```
"contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Also you're not performing server-side processing correctly. You need to use `ssp.class.php` helper available in jQuery DataTables distribution or switch to client-side processing mode.

To switch to client-side processing mode, *remove* the following options in your JavaScript code:

```
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
```

In your PHP code, just return your data as follows:

```
$response = array(
    "data" => $data
);
```

Also your data is in `$data` not `$users`.

Comment: array (size=4)
  'draw' => null
  'recordsTotal' => int 28
  'recordsFiltered' => int 28
  'data' =>   I'm getting this when I return response

Comment: : do I have to pass  $_REQUEST["draw"], on js file as well?

Comment: @Tharuperera, there were some more errors in your code, updated my answer.

Comment: still same. {"draw":null,"recordsTotal":28,"recordsFiltered":28,"data":[{"id":"30528","email"

Comment: I'm still couldn't resolve the pagination issue. still even 28 records showing page numbers 1,2 ,3 but whole content loads for all 3 pages without dividing it by 10. pls advice

Comment: with client side processing mode it works. But how can I do the same using server side processing ?

Comment: @Tharuperera, if you have under 10000 records, you may be better with client-side processing due to less complexity and more performance. For server-side processing mode, use `ssp.class.php` helper that does necessary processing for you as recommended in the answer.